# How to configure multiple Foreignkey referancing to same table from main table using EF Code First Fluient API

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have to design a web application using existing database of desktop application. As per existing database i have below class

```
public class Company
{

    #region Primitive Properties

    public virtual int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsPotentialCustomer { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsSupplier { get; set; }
    public virtual string SupplierCode { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsPotentialSupplier { get; set; }

    public CompanyCategoryCodes CustomerCategoryCode { get; set; }
    public CompanyCategoryCodes SupplierCategoryCode { get; set; }
    public CountryCode CountryCode { get; set; }

}

public class CompanyCategoryCodes
{
    public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CategoryCodes { get; set; }
    public virtual bool PotentialCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual bool PotentialSupplier { get; set; }
    public virtual System.DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class CountryCode
{
    public virtual int CountryCodeID  { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description  { get; set; }
    public virtual bool DefaultCode { get; set; }
    public virtual bool EECVATApplies { get; set; }
    public virtual System.DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool FixedAddressFormat { get; set; }
}
```

EF Code first default framework is creating Foreignkey with name "CustomerCategoryCode_CategoryID" , "SupplierCategoryCode_CategoryID", "CountryCode_CountryCodeID". I want this Foreignkey name to be consistance with my old database tables e.g. "CustomerCategoryCodeID", "SupplierCategoryCodeID", "CountryCodeID". How can i do it using EF Code First Fluient API. I try to do it using Fluient API Mapping but i got error for "SupplierCategoryCode_CategoryCodeID" as "CustomerCategoryCode_CategoryID" is also locating to same table  "CompanyCategoryCode". Also if is there any option available using Data Annotation then also let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You must manually remap each navigation property to define its key. Something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.CountryCode)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("CountryCodeID");

modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany(c => c.CustomerCategoryCode)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey("CustomerCategoryCodeID")
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany(c => c.SupplierCategoryCode)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey("SupplierCategoryCodeID")
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

It is not possible with data annotations unless you define navigation property and foreign key property in each dependent entity like:

```
public class Company
{
    ...

    [ForeignKey("CountryCode")]
    public virtual int CountryCodeID { get; set; }
    public CountryCode CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Error Message is "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'CountryCode_Companies' on table 'Company' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors."

Comment: Do we need to do anything with ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION ? Its happen only when i try to have 2 ForiegnKeys(CustomerCategoryCodeID, SupplierCategoryCodeID) in one table(Company) try to referance same table(CompanyCategoryCode)

Comment: Yes at least one from last two mappings has to end with `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` because theoretically both `SupplierCategoryCodeID` and `CustomerCategoryCodeID` can point to the same record which causes multiple cascade paths - that is not allowed on SQL server.

Comment: You are right i also try same and its working ok now but i also need to add Public ICollection<Company> CustomerCompanies { get; set; } and Public ICollection<company> SupplierCompanies {get; set;} properties in my CompanyCategoryCodes Class else it will not work. And same for CountryCode Class so now my classes and mapping class will look like as below and working properly

Comment: I can't put long class file comment here so i will give code changes i have done after 8 hrs as system will allow me after 8 hrs to give answer of my own question. Thank to all who try to help me out.

Comment: If you need `CustomerCompanies`, etc. it is completely different question! Why didn't you ask what you really need? That is difference between one-to-many and many-to-many relation.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to make CustomerCategoryID and SupplierCategoryID to allow Null. I try with HasOptioanl in Place of HasRequired but its not working for me.

Comment: I want One-to-many relation but when i try with what code you have suggested will not work so i try in another way which make it looks like many-to-many. But it work after i make it many-to-many by putting CustoermCompanies and SupplierCompanies icollection inside ComanyCategoryCode. I don't know why its needed but without this its not working so i don't have any other option

Answer (score 0):

Inside your context class, you will need to override OnModelCreating and map the keys, it should look something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
             modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.CustomerCategoryCode)
                .WithMany() 
                .Map(mc => mc.MapKey("CustomerCategoryCodeID"));
}
```

Comment: It might work in OnModelCreating but i have used seperate Mapping class and there it is giving me error when i try to Point "CustomerCategoryCodeID" and "SupplieCategoryCodeID" to same table "CompanyCategoryCode"

Comment: What's the error? Are you updating the parameter to HasRequired in addition to the MapKey?  Sounds like maybe you forgot to update c.CustomerCategoryCode to c.SupplierCategoryCode when duplicating.  Just a guess...

Comment: Error Message is "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'CountryCode_Companies' on table 'Company' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous errors."