# CodeFirst table is not being generated as I would expect

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a class called Status, and I also have a class called ApplicantPositionHistory which has an OldStatus and a NewStatus.

However the table is being generated like this:

[image]

I would expect that the table has a newstatusid and oldstatusid, which should be foreign keys, but it generated those 2 columns duplicated.

```
 public class ApplicationPositionHistory
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ApplicationPositionHistoryID { get; set; }

        public ApplicantPosition applicantPosition { get; set; }

        [Column("oldStatusID")]
        public int oldStatusID { get; set; }

        [Column("newStatusID")]
        public int newStatusID { get; set; }

        public Status oldStatus { get; set; }

        public Status newStatus { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Comments  should not be longer than 500 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Comments")]
        public string comments { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]     
        public DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int StatusID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(40, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Status  should not be longer than 20 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public string status { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your non standard naming convention which results in problem when applying default mapping conventions so your FK columns are not paired with navigation properties and EF creates new ones.

Try this to manually pair navigation properties with your FK properties:

```
[ForeignKey("oldStatusID")]
public Status oldStatus { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("newStatusID")]
public Status newStatus { get; set; }
```

Comment: this is what I got when I run the application.  Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'ApplicationPositionHistory_oldStatus' on table 'ApplicationsPositionHistory' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."}

Comment: I was able to fix this with.   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>(); in the OnModelCreating

Comment: That can happen but it can be solved only with [fluent api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660067/how-to-configure-multiple-foreignkey-referancing-to-same-table-from-main-table-u) - attributes don't provide way to turn off cascade deletes.

Comment: Removing convention will turn off cascade delete everywhere.

Comment: thats what I would want in all my databases, I found a good blog post about all fluent api examples and I am sure I would check it out before posting any other question regarding database creation.  Will paste it here for reference of future visitors. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx